# How to pass S3 continuation token from API Gateway to Lambda

Tags: rest, amazon-s3, postman, aws-api-gateway

I have a REST API in AWS API Gateway that fetches json files on S3 and returns them to API Gateway via a Lambda function. I've implemented pagination in Lambda and I only fetch 100 files at a time, and returns the S3 Continuation Token if it exists.

I've created a query parameter on API Gateway to send the continuation token to S3 for the subsequent calls, but API Gateway won't deliver it because if its format.

A valid S3 token:
`17kqE73kRqN1CZ8LJHWui7rlHD7+SHZgFRVQ5gVJAyF90msNxKgc6LiqRgMzGg5HfIJZP/Dc0Zenf8q7Az93KYtfkcRKtwQ6RL8P4cjGyjR0=`

1. When using it directly in Postman, I get an "InvalidQueryStringException" error (http 400)
2. I found by testing directly in Lambda that removing the last '=' character gives the same file in S3 and no 400 error are thrown but the '+' character is replaced with a space in APIG which makes the token invalid.
3. I've also tried wrapping the token with `""` and `''` in Postman, without luck.
4. Calling the method directly in APIG via the test function providing the full token works as expected.

I map the continuation token from the url to the Lambda like this:
`"continuationToken": "$input.params('continuationToken')",`

Any suggestions on how to get the token correctly passed API Gateway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to urlencode the token when passing it as a query string, otherwise `=` will be treated as a parameter separator (subcomponent delimiter) as specified in [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4).

A properly encoded token would render the escaped `=` as %3D

If the Lambda was written in JS, you could encode the token like this:

```
const continuationToken = encodeURIComponent("17kqE73kRqN1CZ8LJHWui7rlHD7+SHZgFRVQ5gVJAyF90msNxKgc6LiqRgMzGg5HfIJZP/Dc0Zenf8q7Az93KYtfkcRKtwQ6RL8P4cjGyjR0=")
// continuationToken is now 17kqE73kRqN1CZ8LJHWui7rlHD7%2BSHZgFRVQ5gVJAyF90msNxKgc6LiqRgMzGg5HfIJZP%2FDc0Zenf8q7Az93KYtfkcRKtwQ6RL8P4cjGyjR0%3D
```